# ObjectiveC - How to access OS X service "Summarize"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to use [Summarize Service](http://gigaom.com/2009/06/09/get-to-the-point-os-xs-summarize-service/) in your own Cocoa app?

ie. call a method with the text you want to summarize as a parameter and it would return you summarized text.

P.S. I would prefer doing this completely on the backend. That means without displaying the Apple's Summarize GUI at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use NSPerformService().

Sample code here xcdoc://osx/samplecode/PhotoSearch/Introduction/Intro.html (this URL isn’t recognized by StackOverflow but does work in Safari).